# cannot display the data got via ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just want to display following information which I got from my controller via ajax call:

```
{"results":{"name":"Bob","city":"Ottawa","reg_date":"12-Feb-2004"}}
```

Here is my controller:

```
$data["results"] = $this->my_model->did_get_data($user_id);
                echo json_encode($data);
```

Here is My view:

```
<div id="display"></div>
```

Here is my JS file:

```
$.get('controller/get_data', function (data) {

            $( "#display").text(data.results); //???

    }, "json");
```

Comment: When you `console.log(data)` in the callback, what is printed to the console?

Comment: Object {results: Object}

Comment: What happen if you try `$( "#display").text(JSON.stringify(data.results));` ?

Comment: try `$("#display").text("something");` and see if it works before you put some data into it

Comment: `data.results` is going to print as `[Object object]`. You need to specify the specific attributes you want to print

Comment: @Brennan is right, you have to specify the attributes to display. `$("#display").text(data.results.name);` for example

Comment: I want to display name, city and reg_date. I tried in this way as well but still nothing appeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to display all the attributes inside data then you can do it like this:

```
$.get('controller/get_data', function (data) {

   var name = data.results.name;
   var city = data.results.city;
   var reg_date = data.results.reg_date;

            $("#display").text("name :" + name + ", city:" + city + ", reg date:" + reg_date);

    }, "json");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display those attributes, you need to specify them individually:

```
var string = "Name: "+data.results.name+", City:"+data.results.city;
$( "#display").text(string);
```

Or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario is not well explained. What is the error u get? And have u checked if $("#display") exists?

However there is one thing you could do:

```
$.get('controller/get_data', function (data) {

            $( "#display").text(JSON.stringify(data.results)); //???

    }, "json");
```

The above is if you want to print for checking purpose however if your #display should have only the values of your data i.e. name and such then you need to use the above answer i.e.

```
var name = data.results.name;

$("#display").html(name);
```